# Incompatible Types error Java class

Tags: java

I just started Java three weeks ago and everything has been going great. Though I have encountered a problem with one of my classes. When selecting "new Fleet" on the Fleet class and filling in the appropriate parameter fields I get `Error:incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Ship.` I've looked through posts and discussions on various similar issues but didn't find anything that aided me.

This is an assignment for a project at school and I would greatly appreciate i you do understand it, not to give me the answer outright but just sort of point me in the right direction.

PROMPT:
Problem Statement

You have been commissioned by the US Navy to develop a system for tracking the amount of fuel consumed by fleets of ships. Each ship has a name (ex: "USS Montana"), fuel capacity (the maximum amount of fuel the ship can carry), and amount of fuel currently onboard. In this problem, fuel is measured in "units" and the capacity of each ship is an integer number (ex: The carrier's capacity is 125 fuel units). Each fleet has exactly four ships in it. When a fleet is deployed, each ship in the fleet is deployed. When a ship is deployed, it consumes half of the fuel it has onboard. When a fleet is refueled, each ship in the fleet is refueled. When a ship is refueled, it is totally filled up (its onboard amount equals its capacity).

Assignment

Create a BlueJ project called Outlab2, add a class called Driver and paste this code into it. Driver should not be modified.
Carefully review the Driver as it contains clues about the structure of the rest of the program.
Your Fleet class needs 4 methods:
A constructor that takes 4 Ships as parameters.
A method called deploy that will deploy each ship in the fleet.
A method called refuel that will refuel each ship in the fleet.
A method called printSummary that will print, for each ship, the ship's name and the total number of fuel units that ship has consumed throughout its existence.
From reviewing the Driver, you can see that you will need a Ship class as well. The constructor of this class will take the ship's name and fuel capacity as parameters.
Infer from the Problem Statement what instance variable and methods you need in the Ship class.

This is my code:
Ship class

Here's what I've tried:

Ship Class:

```
 /**
 * Ship's name, fuel levels, and fuel usage.
 * 
 * @author JGW 
 * @version 11/20/15
 */
public class Ship
{
    public String name;
    public int fuelcapacity;
    public int fuelcurrent;
    public int fuelconsumed;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Fleet
     */
    public Ship(String n, int cap)
    {
        name = n;
        fuelcapacity = cap;
        fuelcurrent = fuelcapacity;
    }
    public void deploy()
    {
        fuelconsumed += fuelcurrent/2; //Adds the fuel used to the lifetime total consumption.
        fuelcurrent = fuelcurrent/2;  //Divides the current fuel in half.
    }
    public void reFuel()
    {
        fuelcurrent = fuelcapacity; //Refills the ship's fuel to maximum capacity.
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getFuelconsumed()
    {
        int x = fuelconsumed; //Returns total fuel consumed.
        return x;
    }

Fleet class:


    /**
     * Calls upon methods for 4 different Ships as well as showing their lifetime fuel usage.
     * 
     * @author JGW 
     * @version 11/20/15
     */
    public class Fleet
    {
        public Ship ship1;
        public Ship ship2;
        public Ship ship3;
        public Ship ship4;
        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Fleet
         */
        public Fleet(Ship s1, Ship s2, Ship s3, Ship s4)
        {
            ship1 = s1;
            ship2 = s2;
            ship3 = s3;
            ship4 = s4;
        }
        public void deploy()
        {
            ship1.deploy();  //Deploys all 4 ships.
            ship2.deploy();
            ship3.deploy();
            ship4.deploy();
        }
        public void reFuel()
        {
            ship1.reFuel();  //Refuels all 4 ships.
            ship2.reFuel();
            ship3.reFuel();
            ship4.reFuel();
        }
        public void printSummary()
        {
            System.out.println(ship1.getName() + " " + ship1.getFuelconsumed()); 
            System.out.println(ship2.getName() + " " + ship2.getFuelconsumed());
            System.out.println(ship3.getName() + " " + ship3.getFuelconsumed());
            System.out.println(ship4.getName() + " " + ship4.getFuelconsumed());
            //Prints out how much fuel each ship has used.
        }
    }
```

Driver class:

```
/**
 * Driver for Outlab2.
 */
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Creating 4 instances of Ship
        Ship ship1 = new Ship("Carrier", 150);
        Ship ship2 = new Ship("Anti-Submarine", 35);
        Ship ship3 = new Ship("Patrol", 22);
        Ship ship4 = new Ship("Destroyer", 83);

        //Creating instance of Fleet
        Fleet fleet1 = new Fleet(ship1, ship2, ship3, ship4);

        //Deploying the fleet twice
        fleet1.deploy();
        fleet1.deploy();

        //Refuel the fleet once
        fleet1.reFuel();

        //Print summary
        fleet1.printSummary();
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What line is giving that error?

Comment: Please edit the post again and mark the line with a comment - there's no line numbering as you post to SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code compiled fine for me.  Make sure you are running the right files, and that everything is saved.  A common beginner error in eclipse is selecting the wrong active project.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what it was, I didn't have the right active project.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
When selecting "new Fleet" on the Fleet class 
and filling in the appropriate parameter fields I get 
Error:incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Ship.
```

Tells me you're passing in a string into the constructor like this:

```
Fleet fleet1 = new Fleet("ship1", "ship2", "ship3", "ship4");
```

However this would fail, and the code that you've passed in your question doesn't do this.  I suspect you are not showing us your complete code.

Double check what you have is what you posted, and verify the variable you are passing is indeed a Ship, and not a String.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't read the assignment, but your code is fine , no errors  at all, I've just complied it and it works